# ldc.i4.m1 and ldc.i4.M1 in CIL

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I'm trying to figure out some CIL code. I think there are two statements do the same thing. These are

```
ldc.i4.m1
```

and

```
ldc.i4.M1
```

Can you tell what is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia [List of CIL instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions):

```
0x15    ldc.i4.M1   Push -1 of type int32 onto the stack as int32 (alias for ldc.i4.m1).
```

They appear to be the same.

Comment: I didn't know it, I would not ask this question.